# Using C# How can I parse this string to a Time

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a C# Visual Studio web application that uses Telerik RadTimePickers to collect the start time and end times, formatted as 24 hour time.  These two elements get stored in the database as a string formatted as 09:00:00-09:30:00.

Now when the application retrieves the data from the database I need to convert that string into 2 separate times, in the 24 hour format, so I can use those values as the Selected Time for the RadTimePickers.

I use the code below to extract the two dates from the string;

```
if (Results.TimeOfDay != "-" || Results.TimeOfDay != null)
                    {                        
                            string[] times = Results.TimeOfDay.Split('-');
                            string time1 = times[0];
                            RadTimePicker1.SelectedTime = ParseTime(time1);
                            string time2 = times[1];
                            RadTimePicker2.SelectedTime = ParseTime(time2);
                    }
```

The Code for ParseTime looks like this:

```
 static public TimeSpan ParseTime(string input)
    {
        TimeSpan output;
        var ok = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(input, @"hh\:mm\:tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,out output);
        return output;
    }
```

But it is not working, the var ok value returns false and the output value is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.
New to C# and cannot figure out how to fix this problem.  Can someone help please

Based on comments I changed the code to parse to this

```
     static public TimeSpan ParseTime(string input)
    {
        TimeSpan output;
        var ok = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(input, @"hh\:mm\:tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,out output);
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Your format should be `HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: Also, `if (Results.TimeOfDay != "-" || Results.TimeOfDay != null)` will alway be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Results.TimeOfDay != "-" || Results.TimeOfDay != null)
```

This will always be true, because you are asking if .TimeOfDay, or "09:00:00-09:30:00", is not equal to "-". You should use `Results.TimeOfDay.Contains("-")` instead.

Also,

```
@"h:mm tt"
```

This should be `@"hh:mm:tt"`

Edit: sorry should be `@"hh\:mm\:ss"`

Comment: For parsing a `DateTime` it should use `HH` to do 24 hour time and `ss` for seconds not `tt`.  If they switch to parsing `TimeSpan` then it would be `@"hh\:mm\:ss"`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  I have modified the code in my post to change over to a timespan but it is still not working.  TryParse still returning false

Comment: @Perry You have the wrong format for `TimeSpan`.  You have to use `@"hh\:mm\:ss"` for parsing it as a `TimeSpan`

Comment: Yes yes, juharr, I forgot the backslashes - I amended the answer. I don't understand why you're talking about `DateTime` though, noone has mentioned it.

Comment: @RasmusEdvardsen The original and first example is parsing to `DateTime` and then using `output.Subtract(output.Date)` to get the `TimeSpan`

Comment: Bases on the comments I have modifies the parse code but it is still failing and returning the time as 00:00:00

Comment: @Perry Are you sure `TimeOfDay` is exactly `"09:00:00-09:30:00"`?  If it's actually `"09:00:00 - 09:30:00"` then you'd need to trim the whitespace before parsing.

Comment: @Perry Also you still have `tt` instead of `ss` in your format

Answer (score 0):

You can just parse it as a `TimeSpan` with the following code

```
TimeSpan.TryParseExact(input, @"hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out output);
```

Note for `TimeSpan` you have to use `hh` rather than `HH` for `DateTime` and you have to delimit the colons.

Note you really should also check the return of `TryParseExact` and do something to handle when the input does not match the format.  Otherwise the resulting `output` will be the default for `TimeSpan` which is 00:00:00

As other's have mentioned `if (Results.TimeOfDay != "-" || Results.TimeOfDay != null)` will always be true.  If you change it to `if (Results.TimeOfDay != "-" && Results.TimeOfDay != null)` then you'll skip the parsing when `TimeOfDay` is null or equal to "-".  Although you really should handle all the error cases which would be `TimeOfDay` is null, `TimeOfDay` does not contain a `-` or contains multiples and when the values on each side of the `-` are not formatted correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I will address the if statement.  However the C# code to parse the time you provided has an error message that states "Argument 4 may not be passed with the 'out' key.  Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Perry Yeah, it should have been `TryParseExact` instead of `ParseExact`.